# HTML Element styling not working in scoped style

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

For some reason my element styling isn't working when using scoped. When inspecting the element the styling is not applied when using scoped. I need to use scoped because I want the styling only be applied within this component. I'm using nuxt.js, no idea if this has anything to do with the problem.

Not working:

```
<style scoped>

    a {
        color: red !important;
        text-decoration: underline !important;
    }

</style>
```

Working:

```
<style>

    a {
        color: red !important;
        text-decoration: underline !important;
    }

</style>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the `a` in relation to the `<style>`? Can you provide a Codepen/Codesandbox repro?

Comment: `<a> ` has to be within the component, not a slot within the component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in [the relevant documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html), scoped CSS applies a `data-` attribute to all selectors in the provided CSS so that it only applies to the elements of the component, not outside of it, nor to nested sub-components.

For example, with this markup:

```
<app>
  <a>outside link</a>
  <Parent>
    <a>parent link</a>
    <Child>
      <a>child link</a>
    </Child>
  </Parent>
</app>
```

`scoped` CSS of `<Parent>` will only affect parent link and will not affect the outside link ***nor*** the child link.

From what you're describing, you are trying to style a sub-component link.

---

To make your scoped CSS selectors affect deeply (apply to sub-components as well) you have to use the deep `>>>` combinator:

```
<style scoped>
  * >>> a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
</style>
```

To see it in action, consider [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-i0v83).